# Conditional publishing to Artifactory from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ivy, artifactory

Conditional publishing to Artifactory from Jenkins.

We have a set of Jenkins jobs which compile, run unit test and publish an integration (snapshot) version of the library to Artifactory.
These jobs have two triggers: a SCM and an Ivy trigger. That is the job is either run when a commit occures or when a new version of a dependency is published.
So far so good.

However, we would like to make the publishing to Artifactory conditional, so that a publish does not occur if build cause was Ivy-trigger, only on Scm and manual trigger.
This because on ivy trigger we only want to run compilation and unit test to achive contionus integration, and a published artifact would be identical to the previous version.
The conditional publish will also avoid trigger a chain-reaction, having possibly all our code re-compiled and published on every commit.

There are two points where i can try to implement this.

- In the Jenkins job. Found no way of achiving this.
- In Artifactory, as a Build.beforeSave() groovy plugin script. I have access to the variables, ie
  "buildInfo.env.BUILD_CAUSE" : "SCMTRIGGER",
  "buildInfo.env.BUILD_CAUSE" : "MANUALTRIGGER",
  However, if I continue I probably have to abort the save with an exception. If the exception is at all passed through, it will probably mark my build as a failure, which was not the 
  intention.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

For Artifactory team, see this as a feature request: Add options in Jenkins UI to only continue with publish on a specific set of triggers that started the build (ivy, scm, url, script, fs, buildresult)
Those triggers are avaialbe from the XTrigger plugin.

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: has any resolution been met on these?